# ASP.NET - onclick attribute added to Button means page cannot determine source of postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I've just added some JavaScript to the onclick of a Button in ASP.NET to disable the button (in order to prevent the user submitting the form twice).

When I click this button, the page posts back fine but no control event handler runs - ASP.NET seems unable to determine which control posted the page back.

I'm a bit stumped by this unexpected behaviour. Can anyone explain it and suggest an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET Button control or an HTML button? If it's an ASP.NET Button control, is the JavaScript in OnClick or OnClientClick?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET Button server control. I've added onlick="Foo();" directly to the markup by extending the control (i.e. through inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
     OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = true;    __doPostBack('__Page', '');" 
     onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

It'll come through with no extra request inspection needed.

After your comment about how you add the onclick:
Just add _*doPostBack('*_Page', 'YOURBUTTONNAME') and inspect the event args on the server side.

Comment: I'll try this, but at first glance I can't see why it would get around the HTML issue that DevelopingChris mentioned. Disabled controls just don't post anything.

Comment: I'm happy to work with things I don't understand! I'll check it out tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but I had to tweak it. The __doPostBack call needs the button's name attribute in the first argument, not the second. Then no additional coding (e.g. server side inspection of the posted fields) is required.

Answer (score 3):

If you disable the button before it posts back, the server side event is not registered.

The easier way to handle this is to hide the button after click, or create a handler that keeps the second click from cascading to the form post.

Last time I had this problem using .style.display = "none" in the onclientclick did the trick I needed.
Disabled is not just a style, its a state, that the server respects.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="javascript:this.style.display = 'none'" 
 onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: lol. I would NEVER have thought of this, but yes, you're quite right. Thank you!

Comment: This is the correct answer to the first part of my question, i.e. why is this problem happening? I have marked Eluvitar's answer as correct since it provides a solution.

Comment: It works but its brittle, if you were to put that button inside of an ajax container, his solution would not allow the container to capture the click and do its magic unobtrusively. 6 or a 1/2 dozen for today, big difference if you salt and pepper this throughout a system.